# Canonical way to parse the command line into arguments in plain C Windows API

Tags: winapi, parsing

In a Windows program, what is the canonical way to parse the command line obtained from GetCommandLine into multiple arguments, similar to the argv array in Unix?  It seems that CommandLineToArgvW does this for a Unicode command line, but I can't find a non-Unicode equivalent.  Should I be using Unicode or not?  If not, how do I parse the command line?

Comment: [This article](http://alter.org.ua/docs/win/args/) claims to provide an ANSI version of CommandLineToArgvW.

Answer (score 20):

Here is an implementation of CommandLineToArgvA that delegate the work to CommandLineToArgvW, MultiByteToWideChar and WideCharToMultiByte.

```
LPSTR* CommandLineToArgvA(LPSTR lpCmdLine, INT *pNumArgs)
{
    int retval;
    retval = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, lpCmdLine, -1, NULL, 0);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(retval))
        return NULL;

    LPWSTR lpWideCharStr = (LPWSTR)malloc(retval * sizeof(WCHAR));
    if (lpWideCharStr == NULL)
        return NULL;

    retval = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, lpCmdLine, -1, lpWideCharStr, retval);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(retval))
    {
        free(lpWideCharStr);
        return NULL;
    }

    int numArgs;
    LPWSTR* args;
    args = CommandLineToArgvW(lpWideCharStr, &numArgs);
    free(lpWideCharStr);
    if (args == NULL)
        return NULL;

    int storage = numArgs * sizeof(LPSTR);
    for (int i = 0; i < numArgs; ++ i)
    {
        BOOL lpUsedDefaultChar = FALSE;
        retval = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, args[i], -1, NULL, 0, NULL, &lpUsedDefaultChar);
        if (!SUCCEEDED(retval))
        {
            LocalFree(args);
            return NULL;
        }

        storage += retval;
    }

    LPSTR* result = (LPSTR*)LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, storage);
    if (result == NULL)
    {
        LocalFree(args);
        return NULL;
    }

    int bufLen = storage - numArgs * sizeof(LPSTR);
    LPSTR buffer = ((LPSTR)result) + numArgs * sizeof(LPSTR);
    for (int i = 0; i < numArgs; ++ i)
    {
        assert(bufLen > 0);
        BOOL lpUsedDefaultChar = FALSE;
        retval = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, args[i], -1, buffer, bufLen, NULL, &lpUsedDefaultChar);
        if (!SUCCEEDED(retval))
        {
            LocalFree(result);
            LocalFree(args);
            return NULL;
        }

        result[i] = buffer;
        buffer += retval;
        bufLen -= retval;
    }

    LocalFree(args);

    *pNumArgs = numArgs;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: For portability reasons, should one use `_ASSERT` as opposed to `assert`?

Comment: Why WideCharToMultiByte uses SUCCEEDED(retval)? The function returns int, not HRESULT.

Answer (score 12):

Apparently you can use [`__argv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/lt-lt/cpp/c-runtime-library/argc-argv-wargv?view=msvc-160) outside `main()` to access the pre-parsed argument vector...

Comment: This is the most underrated answer!  Also: __argv[0] is just like POSIX: (Relative or Absolute) Path to executable

Answer (score 6):

I followed the source for parse_cmd (see "argv_parsing.cpp" in the latest SDK) and modified it to match the paradigm and operation for CommandLineToArgW and developed the following. Note: instead of using LocalAlloc, per Microsoft recommendations  (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366723(v=vs.85).aspx) I've substituted HeapAlloc. Additionally one change in the SAL notation. I deviate slightly be stating `_In_opt_` for lpCmdLine - as CommandLineToArgvW does allow this to be `NULL`, in which case it returns an argument list containing just the program name.

A final caveat, parse_cmd will parse the command line slightly different from CommandLineToArgvW in one aspect only: two double quote characters in a row while the state is 'in quote' mode are interpreted as an escaped double quote character. Both functions consume the first one and output the second one. The difference is that for CommandLineToArgvW, there is a transition out of 'in quote' mode, while parse_cmdline remains in 'in quote' mode. This is properly reflected in the function below.

You would use the below function as follows:

`int    argc  = 0;
 LPSTR *argv  = CommandLineToArgvA(GetCommandLineA(), &argc);
 HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, argv);`

```
LPSTR* CommandLineToArgvA(_In_opt_ LPCSTR lpCmdLine, _Out_ int *pNumArgs)
{
    if (!pNumArgs)
    {
        SetLastError(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER);
        return NULL;
    }
    *pNumArgs = 0;
    /*follow CommandLinetoArgvW and if lpCmdLine is NULL return the path to the executable.
    Use 'programname' so that we don't have to allocate MAX_PATH * sizeof(CHAR) for argv
    every time. Since this is ANSI the return can't be greater than MAX_PATH (260
    characters)*/
    CHAR programname[MAX_PATH] = {};
    /*pnlength = the length of the string that is copied to the buffer, in characters, not
    including the terminating null character*/
    DWORD pnlength = GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, programname, MAX_PATH);
    if (pnlength == 0) //error getting program name
    {
        //GetModuleFileNameA will SetLastError
        return NULL;
    }
    if (*lpCmdLine == NULL)
    {

        /*In keeping with CommandLineToArgvW the caller should make a single call to HeapFree
        to release the memory of argv. Allocate a single block of memory with space for two
        pointers (representing argv[0] and argv[1]). argv[0] will contain a pointer to argv+2
        where the actual program name will be stored. argv[1] will be nullptr per the C++
        specifications for argv. Hence space required is the size of a LPSTR (char*) multiplied
        by 2 [pointers] + the length of the program name (+1 for null terminating character)
        multiplied by the sizeof CHAR. HeapAlloc is called with HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS flag,
        so if there is a failure on allocating memory an exception will be generated.*/
        LPSTR *argv = static_cast<LPSTR*>(HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(),
            HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY | HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS,
            (sizeof(LPSTR) * 2) + ((pnlength + 1) * sizeof(CHAR))));
        memcpy(argv + 2, programname, pnlength+1); //add 1 for the terminating null character
        argv[0] = reinterpret_cast<LPSTR>(argv + 2);
        argv[1] = nullptr;
        *pNumArgs = 1;
        return argv;
    }
    /*We need to determine the number of arguments and the number of characters so that the
    proper amount of memory can be allocated for argv. Our argument count starts at 1 as the
    first "argument" is the program name even if there are no other arguments per specs.*/
    int argc        = 1;
    int numchars    = 0;
    LPCSTR templpcl = lpCmdLine;
    bool in_quotes  = false;  //'in quotes' mode is off (false) or on (true)
    /*first scan the program name and copy it. The handling is much simpler than for other
    arguments. Basically, whatever lies between the leading double-quote and next one, or a
    terminal null character is simply accepted. Fancier handling is not required because the
    program name must be a legal NTFS/HPFS file name. Note that the double-quote characters are
    not copied.*/
    do {
        if (*templpcl == '"')
        {
            //don't add " to character count
            in_quotes = !in_quotes;
            templpcl++; //move to next character
            continue;
        }
        ++numchars; //count character
        templpcl++; //move to next character
        if (_ismbblead(*templpcl) != 0) //handle MBCS
        {
            ++numchars;
            templpcl++; //skip over trail byte
        }
    } while (*templpcl != '\0' && (in_quotes || (*templpcl != ' ' && *templpcl != '\t')));
    //parsed first argument
    if (*templpcl == '\0')
    {
        /*no more arguments, rewind and the next for statement will handle*/
        templpcl--;
    }
    //loop through the remaining arguments
    int slashcount       = 0; //count of backslashes
    bool countorcopychar = true; //count the character or not
    for (;;)
    {
        if (*templpcl)
        {
            //next argument begins with next non-whitespace character
            while (*templpcl == ' ' || *templpcl == '\t')
                ++templpcl;
        }
        if (*templpcl == '\0')
            break; //end of arguments

        ++argc; //next argument - increment argument count
        //loop through this argument
        for (;;)
        {
            /*Rules:
              2N     backslashes   + " ==> N backslashes and begin/end quote
              2N + 1 backslashes   + " ==> N backslashes + literal "
              N      backslashes       ==> N backslashes*/
            slashcount     = 0;
            countorcopychar = true;
            while (*templpcl == '\\')
            {
                //count the number of backslashes for use below
                ++templpcl;
                ++slashcount;
            }
            if (*templpcl == '"')
            {
                //if 2N backslashes before, start/end quote, otherwise count.
                if (slashcount % 2 == 0) //even number of backslashes
                {
                    if (in_quotes && *(templpcl +1) == '"')
                    {
                        in_quotes = !in_quotes; //NB: parse_cmdline omits this line
                        templpcl++; //double quote inside quoted string
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //skip first quote character and count second
                        countorcopychar = false;
                        in_quotes = !in_quotes;
                    }
                }
                slashcount /= 2;
            }
            //count slashes
            while (slashcount--)
            {
                ++numchars;
            }
            if (*templpcl == '\0' || (!in_quotes && (*templpcl == ' ' || *templpcl == '\t')))
            {
                //at the end of the argument - break
                break;
            }
            if (countorcopychar)
            {
                if (_ismbblead(*templpcl) != 0) //should copy another character for MBCS
                {
                    ++templpcl; //skip over trail byte
                    ++numchars;
                }
                ++numchars;
            }
            ++templpcl;
        }
        //add a count for the null-terminating character
        ++numchars;
    }
    /*allocate memory for argv. Allocate a single block of memory with space for argc number of
    pointers. argv[0] will contain a pointer to argv+argc where the actual program name will be
    stored. argv[argc] will be nullptr per the C++ specifications. Hence space required is the
    size of a LPSTR (char*) multiplied by argc + 1 pointers + the number of characters counted
    above multiplied by the sizeof CHAR. HeapAlloc is called with HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS
    flag, so if there is a failure on allocating memory an exception will be generated.*/
    LPSTR *argv = static_cast<LPSTR*>(HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(),
        HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY | HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS,
        (sizeof(LPSTR) * (argc+1)) + (numchars * sizeof(CHAR))));
    //now loop through the commandline again and split out arguments
    in_quotes      = false;
    templpcl       = lpCmdLine;
    argv[0]        = reinterpret_cast<LPSTR>(argv + argc+1);
    LPSTR tempargv = reinterpret_cast<LPSTR>(argv + argc+1);
    do {
        if (*templpcl == '"')
        {
            in_quotes = !in_quotes;
            templpcl++; //move to next character
            continue;
        }
        *tempargv++ = *templpcl;
        templpcl++; //move to next character
        if (_ismbblead(*templpcl) != 0) //should copy another character for MBCS
        {
            *tempargv++ = *templpcl; //copy second byte
            templpcl++; //skip over trail byte
        }
    } while (*templpcl != '\0' && (in_quotes || (*templpcl != ' ' && *templpcl != '\t')));
    //parsed first argument
    if (*templpcl == '\0')
    {
        //no more arguments, rewind and the next for statement will handle
        templpcl--;
    }
    else
    {
        //end of program name - add null terminator
        *tempargv = '\0';
    }
    int currentarg   = 1;
    argv[currentarg] = ++tempargv;
    //loop through the remaining arguments
    slashcount      = 0; //count of backslashes
    countorcopychar = true; //count the character or not
    for (;;)
    {
        if (*templpcl)
        {
            //next argument begins with next non-whitespace character
            while (*templpcl == ' ' || *templpcl == '\t')
                ++templpcl;
        }
        if (*templpcl == '\0')
            break; //end of arguments
        argv[currentarg] = ++tempargv; //copy address of this argument string
        //next argument - loop through it's characters
        for (;;)
        {
            /*Rules:
              2N     backslashes   + " ==> N backslashes and begin/end quote
              2N + 1 backslashes   + " ==> N backslashes + literal "
              N      backslashes       ==> N backslashes*/
            slashcount      = 0;
            countorcopychar = true;
            while (*templpcl == '\\')
            {
                //count the number of backslashes for use below
                ++templpcl;
                ++slashcount;
            }
            if (*templpcl == '"')
            {
                //if 2N backslashes before, start/end quote, otherwise copy literally.
                if (slashcount % 2 == 0) //even number of backslashes
                {
                    if (in_quotes && *(templpcl+1) == '"')
                    {
                        in_quotes = !in_quotes; //NB: parse_cmdline omits this line
                        templpcl++; //double quote inside quoted string
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //skip first quote character and count second
                        countorcopychar = false;
                        in_quotes       = !in_quotes;
                    }
                }
                slashcount /= 2;
            }
            //copy slashes
            while (slashcount--)
            {
                *tempargv++ = '\\';
            }
            if (*templpcl == '\0' || (!in_quotes && (*templpcl == ' ' || *templpcl == '\t')))
            {
                //at the end of the argument - break
                break;
            }
            if (countorcopychar)
            {
                *tempargv++ = *templpcl;
                if (_ismbblead(*templpcl) != 0) //should copy another character for MBCS
                {
                    ++templpcl; //skip over trail byte
                    *tempargv++ = *templpcl;
                }
            }
            ++templpcl;
        }
        //null-terminate the argument
        *tempargv = '\0';
        ++currentarg;
    }
    argv[argc] = nullptr;
    *pNumArgs = argc;
    return argv;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`CommandLineToArgvW()` is in shell32.dll.  I'd guessthat the Shell developers created the function for their own use, and it was made public either because someone decided that 3rd party devs would find it useful or because some court action made them do it.

Since the Shell developers only ever needed a Unicode version that's all they ever wrote.  It would be fairly simple to write an ANSI wrapper for the function that converts the ANSI to Unicode, calls the function and converts the Unicode results to ANSI (and if Shell32.dll ever provided an ANSI variant of this API, that's probably exactly what would do).

Answer (score 2):

None of these solved the problem perfectly when don't want parsing UNICODE, so my solution is modified from [WINE](https://www.winehq.org/) projects, they contains source code of `CommandLineToArgvW` of `shell32.dll`, modified it to below and it's work perfectly for me:

```
/*************************************************************************
 * CommandLineToArgvA            [SHELL32.@]
 * 
 * MODIFIED FROM https://www.winehq.org/ project
 * We must interpret the quotes in the command line to rebuild the argv
 * array correctly:
 * - arguments are separated by spaces or tabs
 * - quotes serve as optional argument delimiters
 *   '"a b"'   -> 'a b'
 * - escaped quotes must be converted back to '"'
 *   '\"'      -> '"'
 * - consecutive backslashes preceding a quote see their number halved with
 *   the remainder escaping the quote:
 *   2n   backslashes + quote -> n backslashes + quote as an argument delimiter
 *   2n+1 backslashes + quote -> n backslashes + literal quote
 * - backslashes that are not followed by a quote are copied literally:
 *   'a\b'     -> 'a\b'
 *   'a\\b'    -> 'a\\b'
 * - in quoted strings, consecutive quotes see their number divided by three
 *   with the remainder modulo 3 deciding whether to close the string or not.
 *   Note that the opening quote must be counted in the consecutive quotes,
 *   that's the (1+) below:
 *   (1+) 3n   quotes -> n quotes
 *   (1+) 3n+1 quotes -> n quotes plus closes the quoted string
 *   (1+) 3n+2 quotes -> n+1 quotes plus closes the quoted string
 * - in unquoted strings, the first quote opens the quoted string and the
 *   remaining consecutive quotes follow the above rule.
 */

LPSTR* WINAPI CommandLineToArgvA(LPSTR lpCmdline, int* numargs)
{
    DWORD argc;
    LPSTR  *argv;
    LPSTR s;
    LPSTR d;
    LPSTR cmdline;
    int qcount,bcount;

    if(!numargs || *lpCmdline==0)
    {
        SetLastError(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* --- First count the arguments */
    argc=1;
    s=lpCmdline;
    /* The first argument, the executable path, follows special rules */
    if (*s=='"')
    {
        /* The executable path ends at the next quote, no matter what */
        s++;
        while (*s)
            if (*s++=='"')
                break;
    }
    else
    {
        /* The executable path ends at the next space, no matter what */
        while (*s && *s!=' ' && *s!='\t')
            s++;
    }
    /* skip to the first argument, if any */
    while (*s==' ' || *s=='\t')
        s++;
    if (*s)
        argc++;

    /* Analyze the remaining arguments */
    qcount=bcount=0;
    while (*s)
    {
        if ((*s==' ' || *s=='\t') && qcount==0)
        {
            /* skip to the next argument and count it if any */
            while (*s==' ' || *s=='\t')
                s++;
            if (*s)
                argc++;
            bcount=0;
        }
        else if (*s=='\\')
        {
            /* '\', count them */
            bcount++;
            s++;
        }
        else if (*s=='"')
        {
            /* '"' */
            if ((bcount & 1)==0)
                qcount++; /* unescaped '"' */
            s++;
            bcount=0;
            /* consecutive quotes, see comment in copying code below */
            while (*s=='"')
            {
                qcount++;
                s++;
            }
            qcount=qcount % 3;
            if (qcount==2)
                qcount=0;
        }
        else
        {
            /* a regular character */
            bcount=0;
            s++;
        }
    }

    /* Allocate in a single lump, the string array, and the strings that go
     * with it. This way the caller can make a single LocalFree() call to free
     * both, as per MSDN.
     */
    argv=LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, (argc+1)*sizeof(LPSTR)+(strlen(lpCmdline)+1)*sizeof(char));
    if (!argv)
        return NULL;
    cmdline=(LPSTR)(argv+argc+1);
    strcpy(cmdline, lpCmdline);

    /* --- Then split and copy the arguments */
    argv[0]=d=cmdline;
    argc=1;
    /* The first argument, the executable path, follows special rules */
    if (*d=='"')
    {
        /* The executable path ends at the next quote, no matter what */
        s=d+1;
        while (*s)
        {
            if (*s=='"')
            {
                s++;
                break;
            }
            *d++=*s++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /* The executable path ends at the next space, no matter what */
        while (*d && *d!=' ' && *d!='\t')
            d++;
        s=d;
        if (*s)
            s++;
    }
    /* close the executable path */
    *d++=0;
    /* skip to the first argument and initialize it if any */
    while (*s==' ' || *s=='\t')
        s++;
    if (!*s)
    {
        /* There are no parameters so we are all done */
        argv[argc]=NULL;
        *numargs=argc;
        return argv;
    }

    /* Split and copy the remaining arguments */
    argv[argc++]=d;
    qcount=bcount=0;
    while (*s)
    {
        if ((*s==' ' || *s=='\t') && qcount==0)
        {
            /* close the argument */
            *d++=0;
            bcount=0;

            /* skip to the next one and initialize it if any */
            do {
                s++;
            } while (*s==' ' || *s=='\t');
            if (*s)
                argv[argc++]=d;
        }
        else if (*s=='\\')
        {
            *d++=*s++;
            bcount++;
        }
        else if (*s=='"')
        {
            if ((bcount & 1)==0)
            {
                /* Preceded by an even number of '\', this is half that
                 * number of '\', plus a quote which we erase.
                 */
                d-=bcount/2;
                qcount++;
            }
            else
            {
                /* Preceded by an odd number of '\', this is half that
                 * number of '\' followed by a '"'
                 */
                d=d-bcount/2-1;
                *d++='"';
            }
            s++;
            bcount=0;
            /* Now count the number of consecutive quotes. Note that qcount
             * already takes into account the opening quote if any, as well as
             * the quote that lead us here.
             */
            while (*s=='"')
            {
                if (++qcount==3)
                {
                    *d++='"';
                    qcount=0;
                }
                s++;
            }
            if (qcount==2)
                qcount=0;
        }
        else
        {
            /* a regular character */
            *d++=*s++;
            bcount=0;
        }
    }
    *d='\0';
    argv[argc]=NULL;
    *numargs=argc;

    return argv;
}
```

Be careful when parsing empty string `""`, it's return `NULL` instead of executable path, that's the different behavior with the standard `CommandLineToArgvW`, the recommanded usage is below:

```
int argc;
LPSTR * argv = CommandLineToArgvA(GetCommandLineA(), &argc);

// AFTER consumed argv
LocalFree(argv);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is about the simplest way I can think of to obtain an old-fashioned argc/argv pair at the top of WinMain.  Assuming that the command-line really was ANSI text, you don't actually need any conversions fancier than this.

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) {
    int argc;
    LPWSTR *szArglist = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argc);
    char **argv = new char*[argc];
    for (int i=0; i<argc; i++) {
        int lgth = wcslen(szArglist[i]);
        argv[i] = new char[lgth+1];
        for (int j=0; j<=lgth; j++)
            argv[i][j] = char(szArglist[i][j]);
    }
    LocalFree(szArglist);
```