# Amending this program to use getCommandLine()

Tags: c, windows

I have this program

I'd like to amend it to use getCommandLine()
Just, after the While loop, to print what getCommandLine() returns.

I don't know C, though I do know programming..

How can I use getCommandLine?

I know logically,  getCommandLine is a Windows thing, and I have to import something, but can anybody answer with code that actually does it?

If it makes any difference, i'm compiling it with TCC(Tiny C Compiler)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (argv[i]) {
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156(v=vs.85).aspx

You'll need to include `<windows.h>`. But I don't think it does what you think it does. It just gives you the full command line string, in the case that you don't have argv/argc.

Also you might find this post helpful:

[Canonical way to parse the command line into arguments in plain C Windows API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291424/canonical-way-to-parse-the-command-line-into-arguments-in-plain-c-windows-api)

Comment: i'm getting an error when I try printf(getCommandLine()); even with the include, so hence my question asks to see the code that'd do it

Comment: yes kevin, that did what i thought it did..and wanted it to do.  ta matteo, that capital G made it work