# Launching a Win32 Forms application with parameters in C++

Tags: c++, parameters

How do I go about adding support to my Windows Forms Application to be able to launch with parameters?

I'm using C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing Win32 gui application then your entry point it [WinMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
int CALLBACK WinMain(
  _In_  HINSTANCE hInstance,
  _In_  HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  _In_  LPSTR lpCmdLine,
  _In_  int nCmdShow
);
```

The third parameter, `lpCmdLine` is the command line passed to the application.  The command line parameters passed to the application will be in that string.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291424/canonical-way-to-parse-the-command-line-into-arguments-in-plain-c-windows-api

Answer (score 0):

You can either add an `args` array to your Main method or use [`Environment::GetCommandLineArgs()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx)

So either

`int Main(array<String^>^ args)`

or

`array<String^>^ args = Environment::GetCommandLineArgs();`

Then loop through the args array and determine what to do based on what is in the array.

Comment: `3 IntelliSense: expected an expression maindlg.c 290 15 STablUpd`
`1 IntelliSense: identifier "array" is undefined maindlg.c 290 2 STablUpd`
`2 IntelliSense: identifier "String" is undefined maindlg.c 290 8 STablUpd`

Comment: Are you using .NET or just Win32?

Comment: Then you are not writing a Windows Forms Application, Windows Forms applications are .NET.  My answer was for a .NET Windows Forms application.  It does apply to your question then.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18869/discussion-between-user1661022-and-shf301)

Answer (score 0):

There's a `main(int argc, char** argv)` function for any executable program. You just need to parse the command line parameters passed in `argv` and pass theese to your main form.

Comment: I've attempted using this (I used the function and then getting a message box to appear with argv in) however, I get no message box.