# WinMain() not receiving enough args if opened by double-clicking the file

Tags: c++, windows

I used to be able to double-click files of my custom extension and open it via my C++ exe program (right click-> open with -> my program). The program was correctly receiving args.

Its WinMain() was receiving several args: the first argument was path to exe and the second argument was the path to the clicked file.

However, I no longer seem to be able to receive the second argument, it always launches my program with 1 argument: the path to this program.

Could it be because of the Windows Update I did today? Using Windows 10 and Visual Studio (same happens if compiled in Debug or in Release)

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){

    int nArgs;
    LPWSTR *szArglist = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLine(), &nArgs);  //GetCommandLine() is a #define located inside processenv.h
    
    //Now nArgs is your argc and szarglist is your argv
    //first arg is path to exe, second arg is path to clicked file.

    if(nArgs<=1){  LocalFree(szArglist);  return EXIT_FAILURE;  } //not enough args (1 or less)

    LocalFree(szArglist);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You probably haven't defined `UNICODE` and compiled this as C code.

Answer (score -1):

It was because of how I was fetching the arguments.

I was using `CommandLineToArgvW()`, but when I instead started to use `__argv` and `__argc` it started working. [Found this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1399224/9007125)

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){    

    if(__argc<=1){  return EXIT_FAILURE;  } //not enough args (1 or less)  

    /*use __argv[1] to fetch your second argument (in my case it's filepath) */    

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: If you were previously using `CommandLineToArgvW`, you should be using `__wargv` instead of `__argv`.  At any rate, while I prefer using `__argv`/`__wargv`, switching to it from `CommandLineArgvW` should not have changed your program's behavior (unless a Windows update updated `shell32.dll` and somehow broke either `GetCommandLineW` or `CommandLineToArgvW`, but that seems quite unlikely since that would break *lots* of programs).